# AMP Domain "ampproject.org" not available anymore

Tags: amp-html

Since yesterday the Domain:

```
ampproject.org
```

ist not available anymore.

```
ampproject.org > via 301 Redirect > https://amp.dev/
```

but every script that comes from:

```
 https://cdn.ampproject.org/
```

for example:

```
 https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0.js (MAIN AMP FILE)
 https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-ad-0.1.js
```

gives a:

DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN

Is it possible for you to open this file?

https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, I can open it. The first 256 characters are

```
self.AMP_CONFIG={"amp-consent":1,"fixed-elements-in-lightbox":1,"chunked-amp":1,"amp-ad-ff-adx-ady":0.01,"amp-list-load-more":1,"hidden-mutation-observer":1,"expAdsenseCanonical":0.01,"canary":0,"expAdsenseUnconditionedCanonical":0.01,"amp-story-v1":1,"ad-
```

Comment: Thats strange. Maybe they made a DNS Change. I will try a router reset, browser cache delete and ipconfig /flushdns . brb

Comment: ok, fixed. It was a DNS Issue. Maybe the TTL is set "tooo long".